# Show Sum of Columns in Pie Chart Drupal

Tags: drupal, charts, pie-chart

I used [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) in Drupal.

I have 3 columns in a dataset with integer values. I want to show the sum of each column, in a pie chart.

I tried putting Sum(field1), Sum(field2), ... in value fields, but it doesn't work correctly and creates several series. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) is being deprecated and users are recommended to move over to the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) Module

If you want to stick with [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), then [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) will allow you to write custom db_query or db_select functions to grab the values that you need.

Comment: Hi @pete80 i'm trying use charts but it have a message:
"graph with engine bluff not available" and it doesn't work

Comment: @kguest: thx for the "approve" of my suggested edit. Sorry I didn't notice the extra typo you caught. Quick question for you about "my" prior version that you (also) approved. Could you explain briefly why my edit was approved. I mean what kind of rule you used. Especially this question I wonder about: if I only add links to module names (to uniquely identify which of all those charting modules we are talking about), can I then be reasonably sure that it will get approved (i.e. that I'm not wasting my time)? Why I doubt: only adapting tags seems to not be sufficient to be approved.

Comment: If you coherently explain what the links are about and why they are pertinent, then your answer will be more likely to be approved than if it is just a collection of links that people have to click into to see why they are being posted as an answer.

Comment: Please note: there are 2 serious errors in the 1st paragraph of this answer, as i explained in the "note" of my own answer. I suggest the OP of this answer edits this answer accordingly (to correct these errors). I cannot do so without "changing what the OP of the answer was trying to say".

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) as you mentioned in your question, is one of [the typical modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) used for creating charts in Drupal.

Another alternative is typically the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module, for which its project page contains some information that indicates it is "being depreciated and users are recommended to move over to the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module". Though most recently some comments in the chart issue queue contain some details that illustrate that that depreciation is being reconsidered. Refer to that issue queue for more details on that.

If needed, do not hesitate to create an issue in the module's issue queue. As an alternative create a new question on this site (or Drupal Answers) and find a way to let me know about it (eg via some comment in any of my questions or answers around here).

If you want to stick with Google Chart Tools, then [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) will allow you to write custom db_query or db_select functions to grab the values that you need.

**Be aware**: I'm the maintainer of both modules [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), and the author of the documentation of [the typical modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) mentioned in the beginning of my reply.

**Note**: The alternative answer to this question actually links to the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, not to the [Google Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools). And neither of these 2 modules are being deprecated.